# A question about integrate $\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-at-bt^c}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

To simplify my question, I will use some letters to denote the positive constant part. I was trying to do the integration
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-at-bt^c}dt$$
I was considering that if $c=1$, then the integrand can be seen as the kernel of the exponential distribution. If $c=2$, then after some manipulation, the integrand can be seen as the kernel of a normal distribution. But the thing here is I do not know what $c$ is, it actually can be anything positive, so is there any ideas about how to do this integration?

Thanks~

Comment: If $c$ is a positive integer, there are solutions in terms of hypergeometric functions. They are not very nice but, if you wish, I could provide some of them (obtained by a CAS).

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thanks, in the context of the paper involved, actually we want $0<c<1$ but there are no other restrictions on it like to be an integer etc.

Comment: In such a case, what I would suggest is numerical integration and later, table lookup + interpolation or curve fit (if possible). I think that one of my former students worked something similar. I shall try to find some old notes of mine. This will be tomorrow since, here, it is dinner time. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks!

Comment: If the question is about evaluating the integral in closed form, this can be done in terms of the Fox H-function.

Comment: @Maxim. Could you elaborate ? I am not familiar at all with the use of the Fox H function. Thanks.

Comment: @Nan. I have been in touch with my former student. The problem he worked was for $b=a$ and both $a=b$ and $c$ were covering a limited range. What he did was just to numericaaly compute the integrals over a grid and then use bicubic splines for interpolation. Be sure I am sorry to be of no help. Please, let me know if you receive answers to this problem. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's a general result that if you have an integral from zero to infinity of a Meijer G-function of $a t$ and a G-function of $b t^c$, then, due to the properties of the Mellin transform, the answer is an H-function. If $c$ is rational, the H-function can be converted to a G-function.